# Is it possible to create a QTTimeRange from two frame numbers?

Tags: quicktime, qtkit

All QTKit examples use seconds for making ranges.  I, unfortunately, have frame numbers and need to be frame accurate.  I suppose I could multiply up by the frame rate if I could figure out how to get that out of my movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to calculate the frame rate of a given video media by querying the following `mediaAttributes` of a `QTMedia`:

- `QTMediaDurationAttribute`
- `QTMediaSampleCountAttribute`

(they are described in the QTKit docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMedia_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Media_Attributes))

and use the following formula for calculation:

```
QTTime    duration     = ... // value get from mediaAttribute 
NSNumber  sample_count = ... // value get from mediaAttribute
double    fps = (sample_count.longValue * duration.timeScale) / duration.timeValue;
```

Disclaimer:

Note that I have not tried if this works, but that it is how I expect it to work based on my experience the QuickTime C APIs and the QuickTime File Format.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by the frame rate is not frame accurate because many of the file containers and codecs that Quicktime uses make use of [variable frame rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_frame_rate) to get better compression.  You'll notice this in any kind of movie that has freezes frame for any length of time.  See macbreak's [The Road to 1080p, part1](http://media.libsyn.com/media/macbreak/macbreak20060216-001a-mp4.mov) as an example.

You can do frame accurate ranges with the QTMovie methods [frameStartTime:atTime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002391-DontLinkElementID_18) and [frameEndTime:atTime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002391-DontLinkElementID_19) introduced in OSX 10.6.  These will give you the start and end of a frame respectively without doing frame decoding.

For example to count all the frames in a movie:

```
// Initialize QTMovie object called 'movie', disable looping, etc

[movie gotoEnd];
QTTime endTime = [movie currentTime];

[movie gotoBeginning];
QTTime curTime = [movie currentTime];

unsigned long numFrames = 0;
while (true)
{
    % get the end time of the current frame  
    [movie frameEndTime:&curTime];

    numFrames++;

    % If we get to the last frame, stop counting
    if (QTTimeCompare(curTime, endTime) == NSOrderedSame)
    {
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: D'uh voted too early:  
I cannot find any reference to `frame(Start|End)Time:atTime:` in either the headers or the QTMovie Class Reference. Google only points to this post AND a category on QTMovie hosted on Google code which defines such methods.  
Your objection should stand, though: It's not safe to simply multiply the movie's framerate with a time in order to achieve frame accuracy.

Comment: These methods are no longer part of QTKit for some reason.